# Google Play Store - What happens when you have two versions of an app awaiting review

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

My App is released on Google Play Store as version 1 and I created a new release (version 2) which is currently awaiting review. I have discovered bugs in version 2 which I have now fixed and resubmitted as version 3.

What will happen to version 2? Will it be taken out of the review queue and never see the light of day or will it get reviewed and released first and then followed by version 3 at a later time.

Both releases were submitted as full releases and about a day apart.

Comment: No, first version 2 will be reviewed then version 3.

Comment: No, first version 2 will be reviewed then version 3.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns Google Play Store policies and procedures, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746), and [the Help Center page regarding appropriate topics for this site](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).